# How to pass argument to middleware method

Tags: node.js

I currently have middleware that checks if a user is logged in as shown below.

```
middlewareObj.isLoggedIn = function(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    console.log("error", "You need to be logged in!");
    req.session.returnTo = req.path; 
    console.log(req.session.returnTo)
    res.redirect("/login");
};
```

I would like to have functionality as follows...

```
isLoggedIn(param);
```

so I can check for additional requirements in a way similar to what's shown below

```
middlewareObj.isLoggedIn(Param) = function(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated() && Param){
        return next();
    }
    console.log("error", "You need to be logged in!");
    req.session.returnTo = req.path; 
    console.log(req.session.returnTo)
    res.redirect("/login");
};
```

Comment: Where does `param` come from?  Is it something that is determined at the time you start your server and is the same from then on?  Is it specific to a particular request and potentially different for each request?  Is it specific to each user (so same for a given user each time, but potentially different value for different users)?

Comment: Param would be a parameter such as the authentication level of the user. So Param would equal req.user.authentication_level as I am trying to account for multiple levels of access within an organization.

Comment: If it's per user, then you have to fetch it from the `req` object then and use it from there.  That's where you need to get it from.  There's no other place for it to come from because the same middleware function works for all the different requests from all the different users so the only way to get the right data for THIS request is from the `req` object.  The `req` object is passed to every middleware function for this exact reason.  User-specific data needs to come from either a session object or from a cookie (either of which will be accessed via the `req` object).